# How to use MDX Functions in SAP dreamweaver's MDXTEST

Tags: mdx, abap, sap-bw

This is more or less the query I'm after:

```
WITH [Measures].[rowcount] AS
  COUNT([SomeDimension].Members)

SELECT
  [Measures].[rowcount] ON ROWS

FROM
  [FOO/BAR]
```

Ultimately I'm after a row count of the fields after some 20 dimensions are applied - for data profiling purposes. But I can't get even this little snip to execute.  The editor just dumps me directly into the ABAP debugger (where I have absolutely no expertise).

Any advise on what's going wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example tested on SAP BW IDES EHP7.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[rowcount] AS  COUNT([0D_NW_CODE].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * [0D_NW_PLANT].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS )
SELECT {[Measures].[rowcount] } ON COLUMNS FROM [$0D_NW_C01]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems I didn't appreciate the importance of this [LEVEL01].  Thank you, really.  That template helped a ton.